# How can I specify which DataGridView columns are used when loading data from a DataTable?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, datatable

I have the following code to populate a DataGridView component.

It works fine, but column names are defined in the DataGridView and I got a duplicated set of columns, the ones coming from the original definition and the ones coming from the dataTable. So it seems that load is not making any effort to match names between DataGridView and DataTable (I carefully set them equal).

```
Private Sub PopulateTable()

    Dim dataConnection As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim dataTable As New DataTable

    dataConnection.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=user;pwd=password;database=test"
    dataConnection.Open()

    ' Open connection and execute query
    cmd.Connection = dataConnection
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name, type, street1, street2 FROM customer;"


    ' Load DataTable through reader
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dataTable.Load(reader)
    reader.Close()

    ' Assign DataTable to DataGridView
    dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable

    ' Close DB connection
    dataConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Is it possible to match columns from DataTable to DataGridView?

Comment: Don't think so, but you could set `dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = False` if you already predefined all columns. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: It seems it is not an option as I do not get the values populated.

Comment: It's not the Column name you have to match, it's the Column's `DataProprtyName` that needs to match the corresponding Field name. You can set that property at design time, if needed (and you know the Field's name beforehand). Otherwise, as already mentioned, set the DGV's `AutoGenerateColumns = false`.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks, that is what I was looking for